# Load BufferedImage as RGBA?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, bufferedimage, rgba

How can I load a `BufferedImage` in rgba format? I need it in this format for opengl, but there is no `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGBA`, and it would be better if I didn't have to convert it myself.
Thanks.

Comment: @vlatkozelka Exactly. I need it to be in rgba format, but I don't know how to load it as rgba

Comment: i mean did you try ARGB and it failed , i guess they are the same

Comment: How about `TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`? It's the same as INT_RGBA, if you get the endianness right. :-)

Comment: See this older duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391778/create-a-bufferedimage-from-file-and-make-it-type-int-argb