# Crop transparent edges of an image

Tags: java, crop, bufferedimage, alpha-transparency

I am trying to make a function that will crop the transparent edges of a `BufferedImage` only from the right and left side.

So, I found this method of doing this somewhere online, however I don't really understand what is the `pixels[]` array filled with? I assumed it was the alpha, red, green, blue values for every single pixel (judging by the `4` in `(j*width+i)*4` , it picks every fourth element), but the length of this array is `299208` for a `68x67` image (I know it's not a power of 2, just ignore that).

So, how do I accomplish this and I'm curious what's actually stored in this pixel array?

```
public static BufferedImage trimHorizontally(BufferedImage img) {
    final byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    int width = img.getWidth(), height = img.getHeight();
    int x0, x1;
    int j, i;

    leftLoop:
        for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {

            for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {

                if(pixels[(j*width+i)*4] != 0) {
                    break leftLoop;
                }
            }
        }
    x0 = i;
    rightLoop:
        for(i = width-1; i >= 0; i--) {

            for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {

                if(pixels[(j*width+i)*4] != 0) {
                    break rightLoop;
                }
            }
        }
    x1 = i+1;

    return img.getSubimage(x0, 0, x1-x0, height);


}
```

What I'm basically doing in the above code is scanning the image from the left and from the right side, checking for the alpha value and marking the distance I need to crop, but it throws an exception because the loops finish without detecting any opaque pixels (and the images I'm cropping are not transparent for sure).

I made a check and found out that the alpha values greater than `0` are actually above the index of `35000` of the `pixels[]` array, and with the `(j*width+i)*4` calculation I can only reach `18000`....

Comment: The `pixels[]` array does indeed store what you thought. Not sure why the length is so long.

Comment: Is your image already cropped using the `getSubimage(...)` method? Beware that this method *does not create a copy*, thus the image will share the backing array (incl. size) with the original image. You can get the correct offsets/dimensions from the `Raster`. Also, unconditionally casting the `DataBuffer` to either `DataBufferInt` or `DataBufferByte` is obviously not safe, unless you have full control of the input image.

Comment: Yes the image is cropped using getSubimage() before it uses this method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick Fix

You can just make pixels with:

```
final int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getAlphaRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

and remove the `*4` in both `(j*width+i)*4`. This just makes your `pixels[]` only contain alpha values, and not RGB.

However there's a safer (no unsafe `DataBuffer` casts), more readable solution:

### Preferred Version

The changes I made were to stop with the horrible `byte` array, and simply use the [`getRGB()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB-int-int-) method instead. The alpha value can be gotten by creating a `Color` using [the RGB+alpha constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-boolean-), and then the [`getAlpha()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getAlpha--) method.

Now the following code works for me:

```
public static BufferedImage trimHorizontally(BufferedImage img) {
    int width = img.getWidth(), height = img.getHeight();
    int x0, x1;
    int j, i;
    int alpha;

    leftLoop:
        for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {

            for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                if(new Color(img.getRGB(i, j), true).getAlpha() != 0)  {
                    break leftLoop;
                }
            }
        }
    x0 = i;
    rightLoop:
        for(i = width-1; i >= 0; i--) {

            for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                if(new Color(img.getRGB(i, j), true).getAlpha() != 0) {
                    break rightLoop;
                }
            }
        }
    x1 = i+1;

    return img.getSubimage(x0, 0, x1-x0, height);
}
```

#### Notes:

`img` must be of type [`TYPE_INT_ARGB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB), or some other type that keeps it's alpha value in the last byte of `getRGB()`'s data (if you don't know what this means, just try the above code and if it doesn't work [covert to ARGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391778/create-a-bufferedimage-from-file-and-make-it-type-int-argb.).)

Also make sure you use an [image format that supports transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(graphic)) (**not** JPG).

Comment: Yes, it does.
However, I've heard somewhere that by using getRGB is inefficient compared to the pixels[] array way of doing it.